Cmake tools failing to run environmentSetupScript prior to compiler test
I'm running VS Code with cmake tools extension.  VS Code on Windows, my project is on Linux accessing via SSH.  I have a kit defined with an environmentSetupScript.  When I select this kit, and then do a cmake configure, the compiler test fails.  It's pretty clear the environmentSetupScript is not being run prior to the compiler test running.  I can manually source the script and perform a compiler test and it works fine.  Anyone dealt with this issue?  Any way to force the environmentSetupScript to run when the kit is selected? or prior to cmake configure?
cmake: select kit
cmake: configure
Expect success
What actually results is failure to compile test code as a result of env variables not being set properly.
